# How to reset password in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want the following functionality when a user click on 'forgot password',

I want the user to get an email to reset his password.[(i.e.,)A password reset link to be sent] when he click on the link, A new password should be generated and sent to his email

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Drupal already has password reset functionality but it's not working exactly as you want it since sending passwords over email is not safe.

Instead you get a link for one time login where you can reset your password (is it safer at all?).

URL for password reset page is `/user/password`